# How to get access to useQuery refetch method from other components?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

NextJS app, renders a Header plus one of the Homepage/Contacts/About pages:

**Simplified `_app.tsx`**

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: Props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}
```

The Contacts page has several filters and it uses a custom `useContacts` hook (which uses `useQuery` from `react-query`) to fetch and render the matched contacts.

**Simplified Contacts page**

```
export default function ContactsPage() {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState(...);
  const contactsInfo = useContacts(filters);

  // render matched contacts
}
```

The Header has a button which invokes a modal that allows searching people on the platform and adding them as contacts.

When a contact is added successfully, and the user is on the Contacts page, I'd like to refetch the contacts (with all the currently selected filters) so that the newly added contact is immediately visible on the page (assuming they pass the currently selected filters).

It feels that I'd like to call `contactsInfo.refetch()` somehow, but I don't have access to `contactsInfo` in Header.

**Add to contact success callback**

```
onSuccess: () => {
  if (isContactsPage()) { // assume we have a way to identify this
    // How can I have access to `contactsInfo` here?
    contactsInfo.refetch();
  }
}
```

Any tips how to best structure this?

Comment: Does [invalidating](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-invalidation) the query work for your  case

Comment: Yeah, invalidate works if I use partial query matching (not passing the filters to the query). Can I ask what's the fundamental difference between invalidate and refetch? Seems like both are refetching and updating the cache.

Comment: I guess they are not different in terms of final results but each one is better suited for different scenarios. Typically you want to invalidate a query after performing a mutation for example, especially when performing optimistic updates.

Comment: From my limited understanding, it looks like when a query(s) are invalidated, that data is markes as stale, and  when that query is rendered, it will start a background refetch  and this happens even when the query is being currenlty rendered in the same UI in a different comment, wheres refetch triggers immediate refetch,
That being said I have never tried refetching a different query

Comment: You want to invalidate the query, not force a re-fetch. That is the correct data flow. Queries fetch data from the backend and cache them, mutations send changes to the backend and invalidate queries that may have been changed by the mutation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When a contact is added successfully, and the user is on the Contacts page, I'd like to refetch the contacts (with all the currently selected filters) so that the newly added contact is immediately visible on the page (assuming they pass the currently selected filters).

The correct way to handle this is to invalidate the query. This can be done from anywhere in the application and will only cause a re-fetch if the query being invalidated is active. In this way it's safe to invalidate the query in cases where it would not be efficient to re-fetch.

e.g. in your mutation hook...

```js
   const queryClient = useQueryClient();
   const onSuccess = () => queryClient.invalidateQueries(contactsQueryKey);
   //.. pass the onSuccess to the options of the useMutation hook.
```

Answer (score 0):

In mycase, i use `queryClient.refetchQueries` to conditioned refetch multiple query outside my component.

For example

```
queryClient.refetchQueries({
  predicate: (query) => {
    // Every query was called in app life will be trigger once, return true to refetch it query.
    
    // Example: all query was get students will be refetch, whatever class they are
    if(query.queryKey.includes('students')){
      return true;
    }
    
    // Example: only query was get students in classRoomId="001" will be refetch
    if(query.queryKey.includes('students') && query.queryKey.includes('001')){
      return true;
    }
  }
})
```

Easest way for queryKey is bind your query by a unique named and parameter will make every query unique and easy to find.

```
export const useStudentsQuery = (classRoomId: string) => {
  return useQuery(
    ['students', classRoomId], // <- queryKey
    async () => {
      const res = await http.getAsync<undefined, Student[]>(`class/${classRoomId}/students`);
      return res.data;
    },
    {
      enabled: !!classRoomId,
    }
  );
};
```

[Learn more about refetchQueries.](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/reference/QueryClient#queryclientrefetchqueries)